# Joint probability distribution function and expected value

Tags: random, expected-value

Lets say for we have a first dice and a second dice, with X representing the face of the first dice and Y representing the face of the second dice.

I know that E(X) = E(Y) = 3.5
$$
E(XY) = \sum_{(x,y)} xy P
$$
Each side of the dice has a 1/6 chance to be rolled, every combination has a 1/36 chance.

What I can't seem to grasp is what $\sum_{(x,y)} xy P$ really means. What is the symbolic expansion of this, and what is ultimately E(XY)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $X,Y$ are independent and uniformly distributed over $[1,\ldots,6]$,
$$
\mathbb{P}[X=x,Y=y] = \mathbb{P}[X=x] \cdot \mathbb{P}[Y=y] = \frac1{36}.
$$

Hence,
$$
\mathbb{E}[XY]
 = \sum_{x = 1}^6 \sum_{y=1}^6 x y \mathbb{P}[X=x,Y=y]
 = \frac{1}{36} \sum_{x = 1}^6 \sum_{y=1}^6 x y
$$
Can you finish this computation?

Comment: Yes, this is clear and concise, and helps remove a lot of confusion with other related topics. Thank you